# Where in the script should I be placing document.title to change the title every xx milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, jinja2

I have this script that refresh some `#id´s`.

I also want to update the page title which include some flask/jinja2.

I have tried to put `document.title = {% block title %} ({{online_num}}) Online Players {% endblock %};` different places in the script, but I can't get it to work.

I don't know javascript/jquery/ajax really, so it has been trial and error with only errors :)

Can someone help me with where or how to insert the `document.title` so it refresh/updates with the `#main` and `#count` every 15000 milliseconds.

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
setInterval(timingLoad, 15000);
function timingLoad() {
$.get().done(doc => {
  $("#main").html($(" #main", doc))
  $("#count").html($(" #count", doc))
});
}
}); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish when the code is executed. Jinja2 statements are rendered on the server side before the page is submitted to the client / browser. Javascript takes place in the browser and is able to change the page dynamically. AJAX can be used to subsequently load data in the background or to send it to the server.  A mix of jinja and javascript, as you suggest in your code, is not possible. You should load the data with javascript and just as you update the elements, you should also reset the content of the title.

The example for the server has two endpoints, the first being responsible for sending the actual page. The second endpoint sends the requested updates in JSON format.

```
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', online_num=0)

@app.route('/stats')
def stats():
    # Generate random integers between 0 and 10.
    num = random.randint(0, 10)
    return jsonify(count=num)
```

The current figures are loaded and the title updated at regular intervals within the browser.
jQuery offers a number of different functions for retrieving data. These are simplifications of the ["ajax"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. In the following I use a special variant of the ["get"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function which is optimized for the JSON transfer. The function is called ["getJSON"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ online_num }} Players online{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.getJSON('/stats')
        .done(data => {
          let msg = data.count == 1 ? 'Player online' : 'Players online';
          document.title = `${data.count} ${msg}`;
        });
    }, 15000);
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```